# Return value from function and start a task

Tags: c#, multitasking

Is it possible to have a function like this

```
public string Foo()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Foo2());
    return "computedUniqueId";
}
```

The thing is that I want to start that Foo2 task AFTER Foo returns a value. The reason I ask this is that caller of Foo() function will be listening for information with that "computedUniqueId". Foo2() will trigger that information so there could be a situation that listener would not not what to wait for and will miss that message.
So to summarize: 
Is there something(like continueWith) that will assert that Foo() returns its value before Foo2() kicks in ?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible because `return` is the last thing that happens in that method.  After a `return`, the method in question has relinquished control and scope back to the caller.  Period.  The best I can think of is if you call Foo2 from where ever the string "computerUniqueId" is getting returned to.

Maybe if you supply more details we can help out more.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something(like continueWith) that will assert that Foo() returns its value before Foo2() kicks in ?

No.  The problem is that you can't control the listening side of the equation.  If it's important for the listener to know the unique ID in advance, I would split this into two portions, and pass the unique identifier to the task itself:

```
public string GenerateFooId()
{ 
    return "computedUniqueId";
}
public void Foo(string id)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Foo2(id));
}
```

This way, you can always guarantee that the caller will know the ID prior to starting the task (as the caller must supply the ID properly).  Making the ID a custom type could give you more safety and control, as you could prevent anything but `GenerateFooId` from being able to generate this ID.